# Error 20002 on Video Query function in TikTok's Login Kit API

Tags: tiktok

I noticed that there's very few documentation about error handling on TikTok's login kit, so here's my problem:

I'm using the Video Query function, but i'm getting a **error 20002** for a certain user

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x1Q3.png)

The access token is brand new, the video is online and public but nothing works..

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? Facing the same issue

Comment: I think TikTok basically says nothing when their API faces issues, so stuff like that randomly happens..